# what is the difference between observable.throw and service.subscribe(). error?

Tags: angular, observable

what is the difference between

```
this.ApiService.getList().catch((e, c) => {

  return Observable.throw(e);
})
.subscribe() => {}
```

and this one

```
this.ApiService.getList().subscribe(() => {}, error => {notifyService.showError(error._body);

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get whatever you throw from the observable inside subscribe,

```
this.ApiService.getList().catch((e, c) => {
  return Observable.throw(e);
})
.subscribe(() => {}, error => {console.log(error._body);

})
```

Comment: when it is preferable to be used ?